# Automatic Data retirement in relational database

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a requirement of having a  sliding window for data retention in relational database. I want my database tables to have only last 'X' days of data. I know this can be achieved by writing a delete SQL script and schedule it to run via cron. I wanted to know if there is any commercially available relational databases through which this could be done automatically by setting a certain property?

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, it could be excessive resource consumption. What amount of data are you expecting? Any particular SQL Engine?

Comment: I am expecting to have atleast 10M records per day in the main table and roughly 40M records in 2 more relation tables.

Comment: Most DBMSs, including Oracle and MSSQL, allow you to partition data by date and drop off the old partitions virtually instantaneously without impacting other operations. Take a look at the partitioning features of your preferred DBMS.